# SQL 2012 operating system requirements

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I am trying to install SQL server 2012 on a VMware with Microsoft Server 2008 R2. But it gives me an Error indicating your operating system does not meet the minimum requirement for SQL server 2012.

I need some help on this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you'll need the most recent service pack installed on the OS.

Comment: I updated my windows and I think I have the latest Service Pack installed.

Comment: I run windows update and it seems last time it has not picked up the latest SP1. Now all is good and working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides minimum hardware and software requirements for SQL Server 2012 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx).

I think that most likely things to be missing are .Net 4.0 (which should be installed for you unless you are trying to install SQL Server Express) and PowerShell 2.0 (ensure that the PowerShell feature is enabled, Microsoft provides guidance [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976736))

Comment: I already installed .Net 4.0, but cannot run sconfig, indicating windows cannot find it.